# Docker on AWS filling up its thin pool while running somehow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a server on ElasticBeanstalk on AWS. Even though no images are being pulled, the thin pool continually fills for under a day until the filesystem is re-mounted as read-only and the applications die.

This happens with Docker 1.12.6 on latest Amazon AMI.

I can't really make heads or tails of it.

When an EC2 instance (hosting Beanstalk) starts, it has about 1.3GB in the thin pool. By the time my 1.2GB image is running, it has about 3.6GB (this is remembered info, it is very close to this). OK, that's fine.

Cut to 5 hours later...

(from the EC2 instance hosting it) `docker info` returns:

```
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-docker--pool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3 kB
 Base Device Size: 107.4 GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file:
 Metadata file:
 Data Space Used: 8.489 GB
 Data Space Total: 12.73 GB
 Data Space Available: 4.245 GB
```

`lvs` agrees.

In another few hours that will grow to be 12.73GB used and 0 B free.

dmesg will report:

```
[2077620.433382] Buffer I/O error on device dm-4, logical block 2501385
[2077620.437372] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-4): ext4_end_bio:329: I/O error -28 writing to inode 4988708 (offset 0 size 8388608 starting block 2501632)
[2077620.444394] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-4): ext4_end_bio:329: I/O error     
[2077620.473581] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-4): ext4_end_bio:329: I/O error -28 writing to inode 4988708 (offset 8388608 size 5840896 starting block 2502912)
[2077623.814437] Aborting journal on device dm-4-8.
[2077649.052965] EXT4-fs error (device dm-4): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[2077649.058116] EXT4-fs (dm-4): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

Yet hardly any space is used in the container itself...
(inside the Docker container:) `df -h`

```
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-394781-1exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                  99G  1.7G   92G   2% /
tmpfs                                                                                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1                                                                             25G  1.4G   24G   6% /etc/hosts
shm                                                                                    64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

`du -sh /`

```
1.7G    /
```

How can this space be filling up? My programs are doing very low-volume logging, and the log files are extremely small. I have good reason not to write them to stdout/stderr.

```
xxx@xxxxxx:/var/log# du -sh .
6.2M    .
```

I also did `docker logs` and the output is less than 7k:

```
>docker logs ecs-awseb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx > w4
>ls -alh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     6.4K Mar 27 19:23 w4
```

The same container does NOT do this to my local docker setup. And finally, running `du -sh /` on the EC2 instance itself reveals less than 1.4GB usage.

It can't be being filled up by logfiles, and it isn't being filled inside the 
container. What can be going on? I am at my wits' end!

Comment: Are you using direct-lvm devicemapper on your local setup too? Can you try overlay2 on the AWS host?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Bjorn I got a hold of the Docker team at Amazon. Amazon is using the Docker storage driver that basically never deletes anything. If you make a 5MB file, then delete it, you do not gain 5MB back from disk, the file just disappears. If you overwrite that 5mb, you take 5mb more disk space. They said to make a bigger server so logfiles aren't a problem and write to a persistent volume. My solution was to attach an elastic volume at launch using ebextensions. Would you like me to give you more details about that?

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave That makes sense, thanks for explaining. I don't see how a bigger server or an elastic volume solves the problem, as that would fill up eventually as well right?

Comment: We ran into this issue on AWS/ECS/EBS multi-container. Our container was writing a lot of logs (JBoss). The solution was to add a Docker volume (not bind volume) to Dockerrun.aws for the container file-system. We also disabled logs to disk, since it's going to stdout/CloudWatch.